# Difference between complement and invert in SASS?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I was going through **SASS** documentation and found that `complement` and `invert` have the same output, Can you tell me what is the difference between these two?

```
//SASS Code
$color:#ff0099;
$complement:complement($color);
//Returns the complement of a color.
$invert:invert($color);//Returns the inverse of a color.
.complement{background:$complement;}
.invert{background:$invert;}

//CSS
.complement {
    background: #00ff66;//Same Color Code
}

.invert {
    background: #00ff66;//Same Color Code
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For some reason, many online examples for `complement`/`invert` use color values resulting in the same output for both functions.

While the `complement`/`invert` of many color values are the same, there are also many values that result in different colors.

Example:

```
$color: #ff6699;

complement($color)    = #66ffcc;
invert($color)        = #009966;
```

To re-word the Sass documentation:

**Complement**

Returns the color that is 180 degrees opposite on the HSL color wheel.

[image]

To calculate the complement of a color:

1. Convert the color value to RGB

   `#ff6699 = RGB 255, 102, 153`
2. Add the highest and lowest RGB values

   `255 + 102 = 357`
3. Subtract each of the original RGB values from the number in step #2

   `(357-255) (357-102) (357-153)`
    `102       255       204`
4. This corresponds to `#66ffcc`

**Invert**

Returns the inverted red, green, and blue values of the color.

To calculate the invert of a color:

1. Convert the color value to RGB

   `#ff6699 = RGB 255, 102, 153`
2. Flip the values by subtracting the original RGB values from 255

   `(255-255) (255-102) (255-153)`
   `0          153       102`
3. This corresponds to `#009966`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you tell me reference name where I can digg more about other color mixing

Comment: Note that for true complement color you would need to calculate to correct color in linear colorspace and maybe use OKLab color space for best results. This is because complement color is supposed to keep the same lightness (luminosity) and saturation (chroma) and only rotate the hue. Computing values based on sRGB values only will result in errors both in gamma ramp and in human vision response to e.g. green vs blue light, but that's the feature that SASS supports.