# SASS - Complement function on a variable from another scope

Tags: sass, background-color, scss-mixins

I have two separate SASS files among many, *on a ReactJS repository*, such as `_main.sass` and `_partials.sass`. They are combined using `@use` on a separate file named `index.css`.

The SASS package as a dependency is just `sass` via npm.

`_main.sass` and all of its variables can be accessed by `_partials.sass`, thanks to  `@use "./main" as *`.

I have the following code on `_main.sass` which detects OS preference for dark mode:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light)
    body
        background-color: $white
        color: $black

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)
    body
        background-color: $dark
        color: $light
```

All of these color variables are defined and they're working well.

But the problem is that I need to use `complement()` function on the `background-color` which is currently active, in `_partials.sass`.

The main issue seems to me that when I assign a variable *e.g.* `$accent` on both ends of the media queries, the variable does not get picked up by the remote file. I could not wrap my head around to do it in such way, since I'm only a beginner at coding SASS.

**Unfortunately**, I need the plain CSS @media query implementations for automatically detecting the preference. But any suggestion is appreciated in case it is impossible to keep it like that and achieve what I wanted.

Thank you!

Comment: can you show us the `complement` function?

Comment: I've solved the issue myself, check the answer out please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution myself.

So, I was trying to make a light/dark theme compliant `SASS` implementation.

What `complement` function does is that it rotates the color in the input for `180deg` on the RGB hue. I needed this to get corresponding inverted-like colors for each color, for better dark-mode contrast. The difference between `invert` and `complement` are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906252/difference-between-complement-and-invert-in-sass).

But, I realized that I did not need that. Here is the code for my theme implementation using `SASS`.

```
// rainbow
$blue: #00a4ef
$yellow: #f4b400
$red: #db4437
$green: #61b500
$purple: #6e14ef
$pink: #ff0090
$carmine: #c6004b

// monochroma 
$white: #fff
$light: #f5f5f5
$lgray: #c2c2c2
$dgray: #6e6e6e
$ldark: #363636
$dark: #232323
$black: #000

$themes: (light: (logo: url("../static/logo-light.svg"), bg: $white, card-bg: $light, text: $black, link: $red, hover: $pink, active: $carmine, border: $lgray, button: $yellow), dark: (logo: url("../static/logo-dark.svg"), bg: $dark, card-bg: $ldark, text: $light, link: $red, hover: $pink, active: $carmine, border: $dgray, button: $purple))

@mixin themeProperty($theme, $property, $color, $additionalProperties)
@if $additionalProperties
    #{$property}: unquote(map-get($theme, $color) + " " + $additionalProperties)
@else 
    #{$property}: unquote(map-get($theme, $color))

@mixin theme($property, $color, $additionalProperties: "")
    $light: map-get($themes, light)
    $dark: map-get($themes, dark)

    @media (prefers-color-scheme: light)
        @include themeProperty($light, $property, $color, $additionalProperties)

    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)
        @include themeProperty($dark, $property, $color, $additionalProperties)
```

There is a color map named "themes" which lists each color for light and dark themes for different use cases.

Furthermore, the `mixin`s match the exact color for exact usage for the desired theme mode, whichever is being used by the client-side (browser or OS), thanks to `@media` queries.

For example, if you'd like to color a `background-color` using the `button` preset on the theme mapping, the usage is as follows:

```
@include theme("background-color", button)
```